# How to make sbt compile a plugin from a git repo, using https to check it out?

Tags: git, github, sbt

Based on an example from the sbt wiki, I've tried a `projects/projects/Build.scala` containing:

```
import sbt._

object PluginDef extends Build {
    override lazy val projects = Seq(root)
    lazy val root = Project("plugins", file(".")) dependsOn( eclipsePlugin )
    lazy val eclipsePlugin = uri("git://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse.git")
}
```

but that fails, as expected, because the git port is blocked at work.

and:

```
import sbt._

object PluginDef extends Build {
    override lazy val projects = Seq(root)
    lazy val root = Project("plugins", file(".")) dependsOn( eclipsePlugin )
    lazy val eclipsePlugin = uri("https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse.git")
}
```

but that gives a `FileNotFoundException` (I guess it's not recognised as a git URL).

Comment: I've been meaning to implement this.  https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/commit/967c3fe75a3c7a2851d66901da2a24513f92644c

Answer (score 3):

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

or to handle a specific external site only, try:

```
git config --global url."https://example.com/".insteadOf git://example.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it out locally and change `uri("...")` to `file("/path/to/git/working/directory")`.

Less automatic, but it gives you control over when you update the plugin.